# Sentinel 2 tile ids by country

Tags: tiles, sentinel-2, region

Is it possible to find all Sentinel 2 tile ids by country? For example, for a country such as China, is it possible to get a list of all Sentinel 2 tiles id?

Things I've tried so far include looking at Sentinel 2 KML in Google Earth. There is also a matlab code snippet that takes input as lat,long and returns tile ids.

Matlab code snippet: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/61640-iskandervito-s2_tilefinder

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but using [USGS Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) you can filter your results using custom shapes, such as a shapefile or kml of china, and get all Sentinel 2 images for.

Comment: Thanks, I need a list of Sentinel 2 tile ids for China. I am getting the images from Sentinel 2 AWS repository which requires tile ids. Would USGS be helpful?

Comment: Coding questions need code in the question body. Links to third-party sites fail over time, and folks here are much less likely to follow a link, in which case the question is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use this function you need to register (for free) at USGS.

Go to https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ and log in.

Now draw a bounding box of your desired area or upload a shapfile or KML. Note that this is limited to 30 vertex:

[image]

Add additional criteria such as a time range or the number of visible results (you can download unlimited, see below) if you want to.

Now select Sentinel 2:

[image]

The results will be displayed. You can export your result as .CSV or other formats:

[image]

Make sure to choose "Non limited results" before exporting if you want to download all results without any limit:

[image]

After a few minutes an email will be sent to you including a link to this file. It looks like this for example:

[image]

Comment: China is 9.6M SqKM. I created a KML for China. It resulted in csv file with a 100 results. Each Sentinel2 tile is 100 SqKM. 100 results => 10,000 SqKM. Where did I wrong? Are the results in CSV limited to a max 100?

Comment: @gobob sorry missed that in my answer. Added it now. When exporting it make sure to choose "Non limited results". It returned 381578 results for my china bounding box.

Comment: That worked, thanks.